# How to fix Android licenses if I can't run `--update`?

Tags: android, flutter, android-sdk-manager

I run `flutter doctor` to see its status and it's all okay except this:

```
 Android license status unknown.
```

It says I must reinstall or update my Android SDK Manager. When i run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` i get this:

```
A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run: C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update
```

But this path doesn't exist. Here's my bin folder, it doesn't have a 'sdkmanager' folder, but a sdkmanager.bat file: [my android sdk tools bin folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suyZA.png)

So how to fix Android licenses if I can't run `--update` ?

In my SDK Manager, my Android SDK Location is: C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk: [my sdk manager's sdk location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAP9K.png)

My C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Android\sdk folder is like this: [my sdk folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImUsN.png)

Comment: The path in the question does not show a “sdkmanager” *folder*. It is for an invocation of a “sdkmanager” executable/script, which *in windows + cmd.exe*, includes “sdkmanager.bat”. So run that *from cmd.exe*: if using a different shell the “.bat” extension might need to be explicitly added.

Comment: (Unlike Unix-like file systems, Windows does not have an “executable file” notation so extensions are used - notably “.exe”, “.bat”, eg, for the same purpose. These are automatically added *by cmd.exe* as a convenience, and can be controlled via environment configuration: search for [PATHEXT](https://superuser.com/questions/228680/on-windows-what-filename-extensions-denote-an-executable/228693)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody has an sdkmanager folder, just run it as is.

Try this:

```
C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat --update
```

Do you get any errors running it? If so, please update the question so I can form a better answer.

Comment: I'm having to execute this command and I get this message [gist](https://gist.github.com/iagofrota/0c5d1d2f25c1b701500657da7f2e22ef)